# LinkageError when try to mock X500Principal in junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, x509

I am trying to write test case by mocking java.security.cert.X509Certificate, javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal using PowerMockRunner. When I tried to import the class for the X500Principal IDE is showing 2 import options (javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal, com.sun.security.auth.X500Principal). I had used the correct import still It is showing the following error. Also the other import is deprecated one.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "$java.security.cert.X509Certificate$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$887d20cf.getSubjectX500Principal()Ljavax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal;" the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) of the current class, $java/security/cert/X509Certificate$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$887d20cf, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal used in the signature
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:59)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:109)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:57)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:203)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:106)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:54)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It will be helpful to see the Java code that causes this exception. The root problem, however, is that the same class (`javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal`) is loaded by two different  classloaders, as the error message states, and it has to do with the way Mockito works (I'm not particularly skilled in Mockito, though)

Answer (score 13):

Found it working in PowerMockRunner itself by using `@PowerMockIgnore({"java.net.ssl", "javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal"})`. The thing i was doing wrong was i only ignored X500Principal.

Also it is working fine With MockitoJunitRunner with out any error.

Comment: I was getting the same error. Annotating my test class with @PowerMockIgnore("javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal") worked for me

Comment: `@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.crypto.*" })` worked for us.